# how can i get the these data array in ui reactnative

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

i need to display the data in the frontend but

i get my data to `lists[]` state and `console.log(this.state.lists)` display below structure in console how can i get the those data in front end

```
Array [
      Object {
        "list": Array [
          Object {
            "id": "123",
            "imageUrl": "http://www.pngmart.com/files/1/Pizza-Slice-PNG-Transparent-Image.png",
            "name": "Chicken Devill pizza",
            "price": 700,
            "size": "Medium",
          },
        ],
        "uid": "xQ0Kg4PgYwVGFTTPGsXK1WHlJuM2",
      },
      Object {
        "list": Array [
          Object {
            "id": "1234",
            "imageUrl": "http://www.pngmart.com/files/1/Cheese-Pizza.png",
            "name": "Cheese pork pizza",
            "price": 1500,
            "size": "Medium",
          },
        ],
        "uid": "xQ0Kg4PgYwVGFTTPGsXK1WHlJuM2",
      },
    ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems data format is wrong, however if you want to extract array info you can do it like this:

```
let finalArray = [];
for(let i=0;i<response.length;i++){
finalArray .push(response[i].list[0]);
=================
console.log(finalArray )
```

Comment: can i save data to firebase without making list inside the lists array?

Comment: firebase.database().ref('/cart/').push({
              uid: this.state.uid,
              list: this.state.lists,
              
            })

Comment: sorry i don't know, but firebase have good document over that